# Finding the PMF of a Binomial Distribution with $Y=\sqrt{x}$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with pmf

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \binom nxp^x (1-p)^{n-x}, & \text{if } x=0,1,2,...,n \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

Find the pmf of $Y=\sqrt{X}$.

My attempt:

$$F(Y) = P(Y\le y) = P(\sqrt{X}\le y) = P(X\le y^2) =\binom n{y^2}p^{y^2} (1-p)^{n-y^2}  $$

Am I on the right path?

Comment: Since capital letters are used here for random variables, $Y$, being a function of the random variable $X$, should also be written as $Y=\sqrt{X}$. And no need to go through the CDF of $Y$; find the pmf $P(Y=y)$ directly by first considering the set of  all possible values that $y$ can take.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, $P(Y=y)$ gives me the same expression as above. What am I missing?

Comment: The cdf is $$F(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(X\le y^2)=\sum _{x\,:\,x\le y^2}f(x)$$

the pmf then would be $$P(Y=y)=F(y)-F(y-1)$$

Comment: @StubbornAtom, So $P(Y=y)=F(y)-F(y-1) = \binom n{y^2}p^{y^2} (1-p)^{n-y^2} - \binom n{(y-1)^2}p^{(y-1)^2} (1-p)^{n-(y-1)^2}$

Comment: The part where you write $P(X\le y^2)=f_X(y^2)$ is not correct as I said above.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, I made the necessary corrections in the problem. Is that how to go about it?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, I am a bit confused on what distribution $F(y)$ is?

Comment: Please take your time to be sure of what you have written. You haven't read what I wrote above. Starting from the fact that you should find $P(Y=y)$ directly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83537/discussion-between-lady-and-stubbornatom).